# Can I use "guy" and "man" with female?

Tags: word-choice, hailnames

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is “guy” gender-neutral?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/is-guy-gender-neutral)
>   [What is a feminine version of 'guys'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19074/what-is-a-feminine-version-of-guys)

Almost of my fellows are male, so I usually say "See you man" or "Guys, I have some problems and need your help". It seems very strange if I use those sentence with my female friend. I want to know, can I use "man" and "guy" in this case? If not, what should I say?