# Boy-o Vs. Guy usage

Tags: word-choice, nouns

As far as my understanding: Boy-o reflects one's behavior while it can also be used to address a group of males. But Guy seems to be mostly used in addressing the people while it is less used as a behavioral word.

Please suggest what should I use and when.

Here are some examples I thought of:

Usage **:**  **Boy-o**

```
1). How's it going boy-o?
2). That particular stare has the boy-o in it. (I think it makes more sense)
```

Usage **:**  **Guy**

```
1). He's a nice guy.
2). The kids asked passing workers for pennies for the guy.
```

Also, I think Boy-o seems to be informal as compared to guy. 
Looking for an appealing noun to address a group of people.

EDIT:

Boy-o *reference*: [Strangers in Death](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=76jg3LngnhwC&pg=PT162&lpg=PT162&dq=That%20particular%20stare%20has%20the%20boy-o%20in%20it%20jd%20robb&source=bl&ots=tdHZX0bn_l&sig=mAEV_o41Z4LXWZ8MC3KWbMo1TL0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=a-AAU_GDHMeFrQey9oDYCw&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=That%20particular%20stare%20has%20the%20boy-o%20in%20it%20jd%20robb&f=false)

Comment: Where do you hear *boy-o*? It might be spelt, boyo, I've not come across that expression recently, it reminds me of a Welsh dialect back in the 30s(?). I don't think it's American, not British.

Comment: Please see the edits.

Comment: I don't think *boy-o* is a term that is familiar to most native speakers. You might be better off saying *guys*, or perhaps the slightly old-fashioned word, *gang* to refer to a mixed group of young people. Judging from the context, the protagonist isn't using the term as a compliment or as a term of endearment!

Comment: boyo is quite common amongst the elderly scots I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Boyo" is a non-standard word that simply means "boy":

> [boyo](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boyo) — Irish: boy, lad

As the dictionary entry notes, it is "Irish" and the most common place to hear "boyo" is from Irish mob stereotypes in film or television.

As for your examples:

> 1. How's it going boy-o?
> 2. That particular stare has the boy-o in it. (I think it makes more sense)

(1) would be correct, (2) seems wrong to me replacing "boyo" with "boy" doesn't really make sense in this context -- but I have to admit that I am not an expert on the word's usage.

---

"Guy", on the other hand, is extremely common and your examples are accurate usage.

---

> Also, I think Boy-o seems to be informal as compared to guy. Looking for an appealing noun to address a group of people.

"Guy" is extremely informal. "Boyo" is mostly reserved for Irish stereotyping so I would avoid it. Neither word refer to a group of people unless you pluralized them. If you did, "guys" would the most appropriate term:

> Hey guys.
>
> How are you guys doing?

There is a question about the applicable [gender of guys](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/is-guy-gender-neutral) but boyos would most probably refer to a group of lads only.

Comment: Thanks MrHen, you made a good explanation and somewhat cleared my thoughts regarding this mythology. :)