# A gender-neutral, informal alternative to singular 'guy'

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-neutral

When referring to an online comment, I want to say

> I agree with this guy.

However, it's not gender neutral (See [this ELU post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/is-guy-gender-neutral).)

What other informal alternate word is there? 'User' seems too formal, so does 'person' or 'fellow.'

Comment: *Fella* is the more informal form of *fellow* (which is already informal here), but in such a context both will generally be interpreted as masculine.

Comment: I agree with this commenter.

Comment: But Hey, *guy* **is** gender-neutral.

Comment: You could always say "I agree with **them**" and be politically correct.

Comment: @Kris `them` seems boring, it kind of alienates both genders IMO.

Comment: @Kris If referring to a group of both sexes you could call them 'these guys' but you wouldn't call a singular woman 'a guy'. If the commenter's gender is not known, referring to them as 'guy' is another example of the assumption 'everyone is male unless specified otherwise'.

Comment: Why not just use the commenter's name? 'I agree with user13107'.

Comment: or I agree with this person. Or that person. Or the comment itself, because I may not agree with the person (we're not talking right now.) But I might agree with the comment. (If Hitler said it's a beautiful day, I wouldn't necessarily like the implication that I agree with that guy.)

Answer (score 4):

You could say

> I agree with the commenter

or

> I agree with them

or

> I agree with this person

In fact, possibly the best is use their name ([Kudos @Mynamite](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193702/a-gender-neutral-informal-alternative-to-singular-guy/193715#comment405625_193702))

> I agree with @jack

Comment: Those alternatives are all far more formal than 'guys'. As the other answer notes 'em' is a more suitable replacement.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use *I agree with **'em***.  It uses singular *they* which is gender-neutral, and the omission of *th* gives it the air of informality requested.  Double bonus that written it can't be confused for masculine-only *'im* like it can in speech.

If you really want to use *this* in your sentence, you could go for an informal form of *I agree with this **one***, although to be honest I can't think the best way to write it.  *with this'n* will get the right pronunciation, although perhaps *with this 'n'* would be the most formally correct (it's a syllabic *n* after *this* in speech) although likely confused with the *'n'* of *and*.

Comment: Downvoter want to explain their issue with this answer?

Comment: This seems not only reasonable but superior to the other answers - 'the commenter', 'them' and 'this person' is clearly not as informal as 'guys', but "'em" is.

Comment: I did not downvote it, but I would have trouble answering with that because it's not a real word. I get that we use a lot of non-words in informal contexts (and I know many diagree with the whole concept of "real" words), but especially on ELU, it seems out of place. I just read a comment on another SE forum today that used slang to the point of being unrecognizable and it seemed out of place.

Comment: @GlennFromIowa what isn't real about it?  *One* and *them* are both words...  That there's an elision ('em) and vowel reduction ('n'), doesn't make them not real if people actually pronounce them that way and we want to represent that informal pronunciation (just as *y'all'd've* is perfectly real, contracting *you all would have*).  I personally find any contraction out of place in formal contexts (in spite of things like *don't* and *can't* are creeping into academic papers with startling frequency), but I don't think any of us would argue *don't or *ain't or the like aren't real.

Comment: @guifa Point taken. I guess what I was struggling to say is that it is not an answer that _I_ would feel comfortable using, and that IMHO, it doesn't seem to fit. But then I also resist using singular _they_, so perhaps I'm hundreds of years out-of-date.

Answer (score 2):

One possible option would be -

> I agree with him/her.

Or even the parenthetical (s)

> In my opinion, (s)he is correct.

But I think you could possibly omit the person in your case, using the terse

> Accord.

Or, the simple

> I agree.

Or, the more complex double negative

> I do not disagree.

Comment: That's creative and clever, but not what the OP asked (nor what ***I***, now, want to know :)

Comment: @DanBron The last two seemed to exactly fit the OP question. Edited to change the order of the suggestions.

Comment: Those are definitely helpful, but they still don't help us complete the phrase "I agree with that X" (which, as I said, is why I l'd like to know). None the less, +1 for the gender neutral pronoun constructions.

Comment: @DanBron "I agree" does answer the OP question, is gender-neutral, and not too formal. Shortening the phrase is an alternative to completing the phrase, and in this case, still communicates the intended agreement.