# Non-gendered collective title for a group of people in a business context

Tags: word-choice

In a work context, what is a good word for addressing a mixed-gender group of people?

Currently, "guys" seems to be fairly popular, but does have male overtones." Is there a really nothing better?

A few examples where your suggestion should fit:

1. "Guys, who's working on the .."
2. "Which one of you guys broke the build"?
3. "We should ask the IT guys"

I'm after a fairly informal, everyday, word, but "peeps" is probably too informal.

Comment: Alright people, listen up. There are many words that apply. That's all, folks.

Comment: What business context is it?  Also ***guys*** (  *people of either sex:
you guys want some coffee?* ODO) is quite informal!

Comment: Addressing them as 'colleagues' or 'team' might be safest, unless you are sure that the group is already used to being called 'guys' or 'folks'. My personal opinion is that 'peeps' is best kept to out of work settings. Younger staff are usually happy with being addressed informally; older workers can prefer a more 'respectful' form of address....otherwise, 'ladies and gents' can suffice.

Comment: For context, this would normally be a manager addressing their team.  Things like: "Guys, who's working on the .." or "Which one of you guys broke the build"?

Comment: In a business environment, (too much of) informality is out of place. Let alone *peeps*, even *guys* would be inconsiderate in the example sentence above. Generally, specific addressing is tactfully bypassed: "Who's working on the ..?"; "Which one of you broke the build?" (That's not an answer, though.)

Comment: Related: [Is guy gender neutral?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11816/2303).

Answer (score 4):

It's very simple. 
 Good morning everybody! 
 Can you check with the IT department? 
 Did you just call someone on the IT team? 
 How do I get in touch with an IT professional? How do I get in touch with the IT person?  Let's get this over to the engineering group. 
 Will make sure that we communicate that to the sales team. 
 Let me check with the product development team and get back to you. 
 How are you all doing today? Or more grammatically correct, 
How are you doing today?

To answer the specific examples I'd say,

1) "Who is working on the…"
2) "Which one of you broke the build?"
3) " we should reach out to the IT team/ department/crew/people." Or simply, "You should reach out to IT."

Fill in the blank… 
 Check with the engineering ____
 Did you contact the HR _______

Comment: Upvoted for "crew" - love it!

Answer (score 2):

How about *folks*?

[**Folks**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/folks)

> (*informal*) People in general.

**y'all** (very informal)

> you (used to refer to more than one person).

For example: "Listen up y'all!"

**Everyone**/**everybody**

> every person.

For example: "Hello everyone", "Hello everybody!"

**People**

For example: "Good morning people!"

Comment: Folks sounds more informal than peeps to me, also it's a weird word to say.

Comment: @xorsyst it will be a cultural/regional thing. Peeps would be far more informal than folks round these parts.

Comment: Also, "y'all"  is a common address in the South. While still more informal than "men" or "team", It wouldn't be out of place in a casual business meeting. Plus, it's warmer than "you people" or "peeps", imho.

Comment: Which south? ;)  Just kidding, I know where you mean, but it sounds totally weird and fake over here.

Comment: *Folks* was pretty common in the early internet period. It’s probably passing out of fashion, like *dude*.

Comment: As an English person, I just cannot bring myself to say "Folks", as it reminds me of George W Bush. And I think people would look askance at me if I started saying "y'all".

Answer (score 2):

It's only 'gendered' since you are specifically making it so. Have you considered simply removing the 'gender' nouns rather than replace them?

> "Hey everyone, who's working on the .."
>
> "Which one of you broke the build"?
>
> "We should ask someone down in IT"

Comment: Yep, these are good alternatives, but I was hoping for a single drop-in word, rather than trying to teach everyone to rephrase everything they say...