# True or False: "English lacks a standard gender-neutral second-person plural pronoun."

Tags: personal-pronouns, gender-neutral, locatives

It's news to me, but apparently Joe Pinsker (affiliated with *The Atlantic*?) says so in [this article](https://getpocket.com/explore/item/the-problem-with-hey-guys?utm_source=pocket-newtab).

> The problem, for those who want to ditch [the usage of]  "guys", is that their language doesn’t present them with many versatile replacements; English lacks a standard gender-neutral second-person plural pronoun, like the Spanish ustedes or the German ihr.

I was taught that the "standard gender-neutral second-person plural pronoun" was "you." (As in "I", "you", "one", "we", "you", "they".)

I was also taught about "implicit 'you' ". This allows me to greet a crowd with "Good morning!" or "Hello!", where the object, you, is implicit or understood without being articulated.

(I've tagged this with "irregular-plurals" because "implicit 'you' " seems to me quite irregular, but I'm not a language expert.)

Comment: I think what they mean is there is no plural form that differentiates the singular "you" from the plural "you"...such as "you guys" or "all y'all".

Comment: @Cascabel: yes, that is the quote ("The problem, ...") I had in mind.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's merely about a poorly stated well-known fact. 'You' does not mandate a plural referent.

Comment: As others have pointed out, the wording in the quotation is not exact.  But anyway, if you want to be pedantic about it, maybe we should say that English is missing a second-person *singluar* pronoun, since we've discarded *thou*.

Comment: @Juhasz The point is that "you" always had the meaning of "second-person, singular, respectful" as well as "second-person plural" (that is it is the exact equivalent of the French pronoun "vous"). Mainstream English hasn't stopped using "second-person singular" altogether, just "Second-person singular familiar" in all its forms. I suspect that this was a result of the the social upheaval of the Civil War and the Glorious Revolution. Also the Quakers contributed to it by refusing to use the "second-person singular respectful" form. George Fox even called the king "thee" once.

Comment: @BoldBen educate me: what was the word corresponding with "second-person singular familiar?" ("thee?") And "second-person singular respectful?" ("thou?"). And is "respectful" different from "formal?"

Comment: To understand some of that article, make sure to consult these ELU questions: [Is 'guy' gender neutral](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/is-guy-gender-neutral), [What is a feminine version of 'guys'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19074/what-is-a-feminine-version-of-guys), and especially [Did English ever have a formal version of 'you'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/did-english-ever-have-a-formal-version-of-you)

Comment: It is unclear what exactly is the role of *gender-neutral* in the quoted sentence. Does English have a gender-**specific** second-person plural **pro**noun?

Comment: @BoldBen I have combined your comments with Johh Lawler's into a wiki answer....feel free to edit.

Comment: The author's saying that 'English lacks a standard gender-neutral second-person plural pronoun' (which is all too obviously false, because *you* is such a pronoun) seems to be just a confusingly provocative way of saying that English lacks a gender-neutral second-person pronoun that is **unambiguosly** plural (which is something well known even to those who are only minimally competent speakers of the language). Moreover, it seems that the author is primarily interested in the vocative use of the pronouns (where some of the clues that would remove the ambiguity may not be available.)

Answer (score 1):

In comments...

[John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler) said...

> ***English lacks a standard anything***.

> English dialects cover all bases, just not for everybody playing the same game. Or, in this case, a recent rhyme answers the question: Roses are red/Violets are blue/Singular they's older/Than singular you.

and also...

> It wasn't a word; it was a paradigm. Just as I, me, my, mine was and still is the first person singular pronoun paradigm, the second person singular (and familiar) paradigm in Early Modern English was thou, thee, thy, thine, and the second person plural (and polite) paradigm was ye, you, your, yours.

[Cascabel](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/160305/cascabel?tab=profile) said...

> I think what they mean is there is no plural form that differentiates the singular "you" from the plural "you"...such as "you guys" or "all y'all".

[Bold Ben](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/191850/boldben) said

> There are three forms of the second person singular familiar pronoun which correspond to the three forms of the first person singular and the third person masculine and feminine pronouns (the third person neuter only has two forms).The nominative (corresponds to 'I', 'he', she and it) is 'thou', the accusative (corresponds to 'me', 'him'. 'her' and 'it') is 'thee' and the possessive (corresponds to 'mine', 'his', 'hers' and 'its') is 'thine' The verbs parts used with the nominate case are also specific, for example 'thou hast', 'thou sittest', 'thou art'.

Comment: It is unclear how all this answers the question. The question was about the second-person **plural**; it was not about the second person singular, nor was it about the singular *they*.

Comment: @jsw29 Feel free to contribute...it is a wiki answer.

Comment: `you-uns` exists and means exactly this

Answer (score 1):

how about "you folks", in lieu of "you guys"?

Comment: Hello, c bach. // But is 'you folks' _standard_, as requested?

Answer (score -1):

Just because something is written down, doesn't mean that it is the truth, makes sense, or is relevant. It doesn't mean it's not either.

There's a lot of context needed for that one quote, and there's a lot missing even then.

The problem at hand is what to do about 'guys'. So some facts:

- 'guy'is entirely male gendered. The sentence

> ?That guy is pregnant

sounds wrong because males do not get pregnant.

- 'guys' is questionably gendered. It's supposed to mean 'that familiar group of people'. It was losing its gender for a while, being very acceptable for even all female uses, but as the author give many examples, people are starting to shy away from it.
- 'you' is both the plural and singular second person plural, but has for a long time been more associated with singular, which makes room for a new plural to disambiguate.

Any possible replacement should fit (not necessarily at the same time) the following examples:

> Will you please move to the back of the room?

> Hey you, go to the back of the room.

To answer your question directly then:

"English lacks a standard gender-neutral second-person plural pronoun." is false because it has 'you', but no one uses 'you' to -address- a group anyway.

So the article is accurate in noting that 'you guys' feels gendered enough to avoid, "y'all" sounds (in most formal and informal American situations) too 'regional' (I doubt it would fly at all outside the US). IN a locative use (addressing a group) many suggestions have been made, but one can use in a natural manner:

- Everyone
- Everybody
- You all

---

To understand some of that article, make sure to consult these ELU questions: [Is 'guy' gender neutral](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/is-guy-gender-neutral), [What is a feminine version of 'guys'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19074/what-is-a-feminine-version-of-guys), and especially [Did English ever have a formal version of 'you'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/did-english-ever-have-a-formal-version-of-you)

Comment: Isn't it rather problematic to bring *guys* into a discussion of **pro**nouns in the first place?

Comment: "That guy is pregnant" could also sound wrong because "guy" is _not feminine_. (But note that it is _females_ that (typically) have the potential for pregnancy, not the _feminine_. My yacht is _feminine_, but I can't make another yacht by getting _her_ pregnant.)

Comment: *"but no one uses 'you' to -address- a group anyway."* - Yes they do.